# RAD webservice generater and *_Deser.java, *_Ser.java

Tags: rad

When i generate a webservice from my DAO in RAD it creates a Helper.java, Deser.java and Ser.java classes. Then when i put this code into my CVS(Clearcase) i notice that these files get hijacked when a call is made to my service.

Is there a way to avoid using theses generated classes? Thanks

The service methods i have return custom object arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally those files should not be added to source control, as they are generated at runtime.  The only files that should be added to source is the inputs/outputs/proxy/soap files.

Answer (score 0):

You asked if there's a way to avoid them. Yes. Stop using JAX-RPC and switch to use JAX-WS 2.0.